# Stata: If I use preserve interactively, can it be used again (nested) in an ado-file?

Tags: stata

I know `preserve` and `restore` make it possible to recover a previous state of the dataset in memory after making changes to it, and that there is only one `preserve` allowed at a time. To simultaneously preserve a second (distinct) version of the data in memory, I would need to save a dataset to disk.

But what if I use `preserve` interactively, and then call an .ado file I wrote that uses `preserve` and `restore`? Will this "nested" use of restore work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preserve used inside an ado-file is separate from any preserve used interactively. Using them in this "nested" fashion is not a problem.

A simple test demonstrates this. First, an .ado file that, inside of a `preserve` and `restore` pair, drops the first 10 observations, with a `count` before the `restore` to document the change.

testrestore.ado

```
capture program drop testrestore
program testrestore
   disp "start testrestore"
   preserve
   drop in 1/10
   count
   restore
   disp "end testrestore"
end
```

Then interactive commands that do the same thing as the ado-file, but call the ado-file before the interactive `restore`

```
sysuse auto, clear
count
preserve
drop in 1/10
count
testrestore
count
restore
count
```

And the output

[image]

The number of observations drops from 74 to 64 to 54 and then increases back to 64 and 74.